# blue window disappear after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make the blue window disappear after 3 seconds I did not move the window, in addition, you can move the window also dragging `mydivheader`

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you considered setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it:

```
#mydivheader {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
    animation: css 0s 3s forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}


@keyframes css  { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

Here is working code:

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
    animation: css 0s 3s forwards;
    opacity: 1;
}


@keyframes css  { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: looolllll :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove your 'blue' element after 3 seconds after you initialize your app.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  document.getElementById('mydivheader').remove();
},3000)
```

Comment: isn't remove only for options (drop-down list DOM elements created by the OS you have no regular control over)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>

<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));


function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  // make it dissapear after 5 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){ elmnt.parentElement.removeChild(elmnt); }, 5000
  );
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>
```

Notice the:

```
      // make it dissapear after 5 seconds
      setTimeout(function(){ elmnt.parentElement.removeChild(elmnt); }, 5000);
```

You can change timer (5000 = 5s, in milliseconds). Basically, what setTimer does is delays calling callback function by that many milliseconds. In this case, a callback function is a simple anon function that targets elements parent and removes its child (element you want to go). When doing vanilla, an awkward approach of removing dom trough parent is necessary.